# How to create and show menu when user right clicks on an NSTableCellView Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I need to show a menu on an NSTableView when user right clicks anywhere on the table row. Just like when we right click anywhere in the browser and menu shows up. [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSTableView` has `Menu` property that can be assigned to your `NSMenu`.

Of course all this can be done in Xcode's IB, but if you are doing this programmatically you need to construct a NSMenu, add the NSMenuItem(s) required and assign it to the NSTableView.

```
var menu = new NSMenu("A context menu")
{
    Delegate = this
};
menu.AddItem(new NSMenuItem { Title = "StackOverflow" Action = SomeMenuAction });
aTableView.Menu = menu;
```

Comment: Gives an error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyProject.MyProjectViewController' to 'AppKit.INSMenuDelegate'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?). Just removed the Delegate = this part and works fine.

Comment: @FaisalGhaffar Assumably you will need to implement `INSMenuDelegate` to access the its protocols, but if you do not need them, then yes, skip assigning the delegate